# Access denied for WriteProcessMemory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

`WriteProcessMemory()` doesnt work for me as I get an access denied error.

I am currently launching the process using

```
CreateProcess(wcImageName, wcCommandLine, NULL, NULL, false, DEBUG_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &stStartupInfo, &stProcessInfo);
```

How do I modify this to gain write access?

I am launching this process on the same machine. How can I get write access without providing username and password?

Comment: Not sure if DEBUG_PROCESS is enough.  Apparently not.  The normal way is OpenProcess(), asking for PROCESS_VM_WRITE access.  It is a highly privileged request.

Comment: A debugger launches the debuggee using `DEBUG_PROCESS` or `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` and would have rights to read and write to process memory of debuggee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `WriteProcessMemory` with correct handle, and **in the debugger loop**. You may read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/writing_debugger_2.aspx).

When you create process, you do have full rights - and when you launch with DEBUG_PROCESS or `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` you have more rights!

Comment: Thanks! After following a few steps from the articles, I was able to resolve the error. I also got similar answer from this forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/8886331f-bbc5-4225-8df9-775159d0305f